# PdfPCellEvent not applying for first cell?

Tags: c#, itext

This event is not called for first cell

```
 public class pdfCellBorder : IPdfPCellEvent
    {
        public void CellLayout(PdfPCell cell, Rectangle position, PdfContentByte[] canvases)
        {         
            PdfContentByte canvas = canvases[PdfPTable.LINECANVAS];                     
            canvas.SetLineDash(0.5F, 2.2F, 0 );
            canvas.Stroke();       
        }
    }
```

Code from comments:

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
pdfCellBorder pdfcell = new pdfCellBorder();
table.DefaultCell.CellEvent = pdfcell;
table.DefaultCell.Border = PdfPCell.NO_BORDER;
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("product"));
cell.Border = Rectangle.BOTTOM_BORDER;
cell.CellEvent = pdfcell;
table.AddCell(cell);
cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("product"));
// cell.BorderWidthBottom = 1f;
cell.Border = Rectangle.BOTTOM_BORDER;
cell.CellEvent = pdfcell;
table.AddCell(cell);

public class pdfCellBorder : IPdfPCellEvent {
    public void CellLayout(PdfPCell cell, Rectangle position, PdfContentByte[] canvases) {
        PdfContentByte canvas = canvases[PdfPTable.LINECANVAS];
        //canvas.SetLineWidth(0.5F);
        canvas.SetLineDash(0.5F, 2.2F, 0);
        canvas.Rectangle(position.Left, position.Bottom, position.Width, 0);
        canvas.Stroke();
    }
}
```

Comment: By not being called does that mean that your first cell has a solid border applied to it?

Comment: yes.first cell has applied a solid border

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this with two things. First, set the actual `Rectangle` in your event:

```
public class pdfCellBorder : IPdfPCellEvent {
    public void CellLayout(PdfPCell cell, iTextSharp.text.Rectangle position, PdfContentByte[] canvases) {
        PdfContentByte canvas = canvases[PdfPTable.LINECANVAS];
        canvas.SetLineDash(0.5F, 2.2F, 0);

        //Set the rectangle to draw on
        canvas.Rectangle(position.Left, position.Bottom, position.Width, position.Height);
        canvas.Stroke();
    }
}
```

Second, disable the border on your default cell:

```
var t = new PdfPTable(2);
t.DefaultCell.CellEvent = new pdfCellBorder();

//Disable the border
t.DefaultCell.Border = PdfPCell.NO_BORDER;
t.AddCell("Hello");
t.AddCell("World");

doc.Add(t);
```

**EDIT**

Based on your comments, you want a line and only a line drawn at the bottom of each cell. Instead of a `Rectangle` you just want to draw a line using `MoveTo` and `LineTo`:

```
public class pdfCellBorder : IPdfPCellEvent {
    public void CellLayout(PdfPCell cell, iTextSharp.text.Rectangle position, PdfContentByte[] canvases) {
        PdfContentByte canvas = canvases[PdfPTable.LINECANVAS];
        canvas.SetLineDash(0.5F, 2.2F, 0);
        //Move the "pen" to where we want to start drawing
        canvas.MoveTo(position.Left, position.Bottom);
        //Draw a straight line
        canvas.LineTo(position.Right, position.Bottom);
        canvas.Stroke();
    }
}
```

However, you still need to disable automatic borders on all of your cells. If you set any borders below you are instructing iTextSharp to draw them for you. Also, since you are calling `new PdfPCell()` we can get rid of anything related to `DefaultCell`

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
pdfCellBorder pdfcell = new pdfCellBorder();
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("product"));
cell.Border = PdfPCell.NO_BORDER;
cell.CellEvent = pdfcell;
table.AddCell(cell);
cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("product"));
cell.Border = PdfPCell.NO_BORDER;
cell.CellEvent = pdfcell;
table.AddCell(cell);
```

Comment: please help me it is not working,I dont want rectangle i want only line and if i use rectangle the width of line get increase.

Comment: Try `canvas.SetLineWidth()`.

Comment: i used above but  first cell border has applied solid and due to rectangle line width increased(i used canvas.setlinewidth(0.5F))

Comment: For me, this code used _exactly and unchanged_ produces two cells that have a dashed border. Can you try creating a brand new project and only use this code.

Comment: PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);  
        pdfCellBorder pdfcell=new pdfCellBorder();
        table.DefaultCell.CellEvent = pdfcell;
        table.DefaultCell.Border = PdfPCell.NO_BORDER;
        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("product"));       
        cell.Border = Rectangle.BOTTOM_BORDER;
        cell.CellEvent = pdfcell;
        table.AddCell(cell);
        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("product"));
        // cell.BorderWidthBottom = 1f;
        cell.Border = Rectangle.BOTTOM_BORDER;
        cell.CellEvent = pdfcell;

        table.AddCell(cell);

Comment: public class pdfCellBorder : IPdfPCellEvent
{
    public void CellLayout(PdfPCell cell, Rectangle position, PdfContentByte[] canvases)
    {

        PdfContentByte canvas = canvases[PdfPTable.LINECANVAS];
        //canvas.SetLineWidth(0.5F);    
        canvas.SetLineDash(0.5F, 2.2F, 0);
        canvas.Rectangle(position.Left, position.Bottom, position.Width, 0);
        canvas.Stroke();
    }
}

Comment: above my code present please help me it also gives first line solid

Comment: please help me problem is not solving??